# lose characters when upload files contain UTF-8 names

Tags: linux, apache, utf-8

When I try to upload some files with names in UTF-8 to server. It seems that several characters is cut off. For example, `Đề thi đẫm máu` is stored as `thi đẫm máu` (`Đề` is lost). I also try creating new UTF-8 filenames on system. And some errors occur that those files can't be deleted or opened. (i.e. `indexá.php`)

[image]

I found that this file is stored correctly in root. So it could be an error of display on admin control panel.

How could I fixed this?

Comment: Please give some example names which show your problem, using ascii and unicode escapes or hex escapes. Also, can you give the filesystem on the server in question?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I've added some examples.

Comment: Could you have a conversion to Latin-1 or the european standard windows codepage in there? That would explain the specific dropped characters. What type is the server filesystem?

Comment: I have no idea about server filesystem. How could I check it? By the way, I've added a picture about the error. And the file size is `0B`.